# Is there a defined order for dispatch_after with same time on main thread?

Tags: grand-central-dispatch

If you use `dispatch_after` to schedule two blocks for the same time on the main thread, is there a defined order for them to be executed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no documentation (that I can find) guaranteeing the behavior you describe.

I looked at [the source code for `dispatch_after`](https://libdispatch.macosforge.org/trac/browser/trunk/src/queue.c) and it's a thin wrapper around `dispatch_source`.  However, [the `dispatch_source` source code](https://libdispatch.macosforge.org/trac/browser/trunk/src/source.c) is complex (too complex for me to dig into right now) and it certainly didn't seem obvious that it would give you the described behavior.

I suggest you avoid relying on the behavior you describe, even if it happens to work in a simple test case.